# Split SQL results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL query that projects several attributes:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d
```

I want to reshape the query results, so that each result is split into a UNION of the pairs of attributes, much like the following:

```
SELECT a AS x, b AS y
UNION
SELECT b AS x, c AS y
UNION
SELECT c AS x, d AS y
```

Is there a way to do so without reformulating or repeating the subquery that projects `a, b, c, d`?

In particular, I'm looking for a solution that works in the SQL dialect used by the Oracle Database (version 12).

Comment: If you are looking to do it just to gain performance,so that  it will not require to query fact table 4 times. First fetch all results using a with clause and then build a union query on top of that.

Comment: I'm motivated by both performance and query complexity (i.e. redundant subqueries). In my case, the inner `SELECT a, b, c, d` is a fairly complex query involving multiple joins and further subqueries.

Comment: The `WITH` clause seems like a perfect fit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`WITH`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm) clause suggested by [GauravS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3927003/gauravs) works as needed:

```
WITH inner AS (
  SELECT a, b, c, d
  ...
)
SELECT a, b
FROM inner
UNION
SELECT b, c
FROM inner
UNION
SELECT c, d
FROM inner
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN rowgen.n=1 THEN main.a
    WHEN rowgen.n=2 THEN main.b
    WHEN rowgen.n=3 THEN main.c
  END as x,
  CASE 
    WHEN rowgen.n=1 THEN main.b
    WHEN rowgen.n=2 THEN main.c
    WHEN rowgen.n=3 THEN main.d
  END as y
FROM (SELECT a, b, c, d) main, 
     (SELECT 1 as n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as n) rowgen
```

Comment: So the outer query cannot select multiple results from a single inner query result? Hence the inner query results are triplicated via the `rowgen`?

Comment: inner query is executed once and then the results are triplied by the rowgen

Comment: @StanislavL - you need to fix your query. The syntax is invalid in Oracle at least.

Comment: @Art I don't have oracle and initial query has invalid syntax. All I would like is to express idea not provide final solution.

Comment: @ StanislavL  - Oracle Live SQL: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d37d/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( a,b,c,d ) AS
  SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT( ( x, y ) FOR pair_index IN (
  ( a, b ) AS 1,
  ( b, c ) AS 2,
  ( c, d ) AS 3
) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d37d/1/0)**:

```
| PAIR_INDEX | X | Y |
|------------|---|---|
|          1 | a | b |
|          2 | b | c |
|          3 | c | d |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> WITH test
  2       AS (SELECT 'a' a,
  3                  'b' b,
  4                  'c' c,
  5                  'd' d
  6             FROM DUAL),
  7       inter
  8       AS (SELECT ROWNUM rn, data, col
  9             FROM test UNPIVOT (col FOR data IN (a, b, c, d)))
 10  SELECT i1.col x, i2.col y
 11    FROM inter i1 JOIN inter i2 ON i2.rn = i1.rn + 1;

X Y
- -
a b
b c
c d

SQL>
```

Comment: Can you describe what the `inter` subquery does? Is the necessary to duplicate the `test` results? The outer query cannot select multiple results from one inner result?

Comment: INTER creates rows out of your columns. SELF JOIN (in the final SELECT) then makes pairs out of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with having all in one column separated by comma.

```
SELECT TRIM (both ',' FROM a ||',' ||b ||',' ||c ||',' ||d )  as sets
FROM   t 
GROUP  BY grouping sets( ( a, b ), ( b, c ), ( c, d ) ); 

| SETS |
|------|
|  4,5 |
|  1,2 |
|  2,3 |
|  5,6 |
|  3,4 |
|  6,7 |
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74c466/31)

Comment: This is quite a different query.